# Confused about deploying my app to heroku by specifying a start script

Tags: node.js, heroku

For example
{
"name": "BIruntimeTest",
"version": "0.0.1",
"description": "Sample Node application",
"scripts": **{ "start": "node app.js" }**
}

what if my app.js is not in the root directory?
I tried 
**{ "start":"node ./sever/app.js"}**

and it didn't work after I deploy it to heroku

Comment: Can you checked logs? Does your app run locally? Have you configured Database connection string properly ? What does your `profile` look like?

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: hi, I just tried it again with a simple code and it worked!
Looks like I got something wrong in my project code

I'll try using procfile to test if it's ok later